# Prove that for continuous $f$ on $[a,b]$, if $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow b^-}f'(x) = L$ exists, then the one sided derivative $f'(b$) exists

Tags: limits, derivatives

If we have a continuous function $f$ on $[a,b]$, then I have to show that if $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow b^-}f'(x) = L$ exists, then the one sided derivative $f'(b$) exists, and also that the derivative function is continuous at $b$.

How close is my following proof to being correct?

We must show that $f'(b)$ exists, or in other words we must prove that $\lim\limits_{x_1 \rightarrow b^-}\dfrac{f(x_1)-f(b)}{x_1-b} = L$. Note that by the Mean Value Theorem, there is $t_x \in (x_1,b)$ such that $f'(t_x) = \dfrac{f(x_1)-f(b)}{x_1-b}$. As $x_1$ tends to $b$ we can see that $t_x$ will also tend to $b$, so then $\lim\limits_{x_1 \rightarrow b^-} f'(t_x) = \lim\limits_{x_1 \rightarrow b^-}f'(x_1) = L$.

Comment: looks good to me, I changed the limit from $x\rightarrow b^-$ to  $x_1 \rightarrow b^-$

Comment: fully correct. +1 for the same.